# Container div not Aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that is not aligning properly, nor can I keep divs inside a container div aligned right or left. It keeps on coming out of the main div or container.

Here's my simple homepage design but the divs are not indenting properly according to this layout:

```css
#container{
background-color:white;
width:100%;
height:1200px;

}

#logo{
background-color:yellow;
width:30%;
height:100px;
float:left;
}


#header{
background-color:green;
width:100%;
height:100px;
float:left;
}

#navigation{
width:100%;
height:40px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
}


#webname{
background-color:gray;
width:70%;
height:100px;
float:right;
}

#mainclass{

width:100%;
height:950px;
float:left;

}


#asideright{
background-color:red;
width:10%;
height:950px;
float:right;
}

#asideleft{
background-color:purple;
width:20%;
height:950px;
float:left;
}

#selection{
background-color:yellow;
width:70%;
height:950px;
float:center;
}

#footer{
background-color:green;
width:100%;
height:100px;
float:;left;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title id="title">DUMMY
 </title>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="dummy1.jpeg">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dumm1.css">
 </head>

<body>
 
 <div id="container">
 
  <div id="header">
   <div id="logo">
   </div>
  
   <div id="webname">
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="navigation">
  </div>
 

  <div id="mainclass">
   <div id="asideleft">
   </div>
 
   <div id="selection">
   </div>
 
   <div id="asideright">
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your correct css

```
    #container {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1200px;
    }

    #logo {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }


    #header {
        background-color: green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }

    #navigation {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        float: left;
    }


    #webname {
        background-color: gray;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100px;
        float: right;
    }

    #mainclass {
        width: 100%;
        height: 950px;
        /*float: left;*/
    }


    #asideright {
        background-color: red;
        width: 10%;
        height: 950px;
        float: right;
    }

    #asideleft {
        background-color: purple;
        width: 20%;
        height: 950px;
        float: left;
    }

    #selection {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 70%;
        height: 950px;
        float: left;
    }

    #footer {
        background-color: green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property as `float: center;` you have to change that property for `#selection` to `float: left;`.

Please refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach .

```css
*
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.container {
   width: 1170px;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color:red;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.inner_div
{
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
  
  background-color:green;
}
.big_div
{
  width: 75%;
  float:left;
  
  background-color:yellow;

}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title id="title">DUMMY
 </title>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="dummy1.jpeg">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dumm1.css">
 </head>

<body>
 
 <div class="container">
 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="inner_div" style="background-color:purple;">
                i'm the inner container
   </div>
  
   <div class="inner_div" style="background-color:pink;">
               i'm another one
   </div>
           
            <div class="inner_div" style="background-color:green;">
                another one
   </div>

            <div class="inner_div" style="background-color:orange;">
                woho! another one
   </div>

            <div class="big_div">
                yipee! i'm another container
   </div>
            <div class="inner_div" style="background-color:red;">
                yehaa! i'm another container
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="navigation">
  </div>
 

  <div id="mainclass">
   <div id="asideleft">
   </div>
 
   <div id="selection">
   </div>
 
   <div id="asideright">
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>


</html>
```